# Error: 'getmapdl' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: errors, getmap

I'm trying to get the map of Africa using this commands but Texnicenter (editor) keeps bring up this error after compiling. I have updated getmaps in MikTex manager but I continue to receive this error message. Any help will be most appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{getmap}
\begin{document}
\getmap[file=africa, mode=gm, type=terrain,xsize=500,ysize=500,scale=2,zoom=3]{Sierra Leone}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{africa}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the Texnicenter call does include the `--shell-escape` command line option? Does your file compile from the command line with the above option?

Comment: BTW, your `\getmap` call is wrong. You must add a location in curly braces!

Comment: Josef: It compiles completely without any error but the map does not show up in the pdf. I have taken care of the --shell-escape issues which was an error earlier before this new error. Can you help me fix it?

Comment: Did you also correct the location problem in your `\getmap` call? Otherwise LaTeX might take `\includegraphics` as location. I can't  test myself as I am in hospital right now!

Comment: Okay. I did put in a location {Sierra Leone} but the errors are there. Can you do it for me when you have time please?

Comment: It's not a matter of time, but here in hospital I don't have access to a computer with LaTeX. Maybe I am allowed to leave tomorrow.

Comment: Sure, I wish you speedy recovery and hopefully you can take a look at it for me tomorrow. Get well soon my friend.

Comment: At home now testing with TeXLive2014/Win, I don't have any problem with your code after adding `{Sierra Leone}`. See: http://www.jklatex.square7.de/download/gm_se_1.pdf  So, it's either a problem with Texnicenter or MiKTeX. OTOH, I know for sure `getmap` worked with MiKTeX at least in the past. Maybe ask a new question with this specific problem with Texnicenter or MiKTeX.

Comment: This is the error message I get:

Comment: This is the error message I get: operable program or batch file, Latex error: File 'africa' not found